# deploying private gem to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've got a gem for my front end (pages theme) I've got access to the private gem via GitHub. It works on local but when I'm deploying to Heroku, this is the error I'm receiving

```
Fetching https://github.com/revoxltd/pages-rails.git
       fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

       Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/revoxltd/pages-rails.git'
```

It's obvious that Heroku doesn't have the permissions to read this, my question is how do I get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps: https://medium.com/@frodsan/installing-a-gem-from-a-private-github-repo-heroku-a895073ae7d

One thing to note is that heroku keys are separate from any github keys so you'll likely have to configure them twice